# Parse.com, disable a UIButton based on an object value

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I try to build a like system with Parse. Here's how I try to do that:
first when a user click on the like button, I associate the post Id with the user:

```
 @IBAction func likeButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {


    var id: AnyObject! = self.object.objectId
    let user = PFUser.currentUser()
    user.addObject(id, forKey: "liked")
    user.save()
```

This part work correctly. Now, I want to be sure that a user like each post only once. For do that, I

check if the post id value is allready (or not) in my liked 
list

```
var liked = PFUser.currentUser().objectForKey("liked") as [String]

    for id in liked{
        if id == id{
            found = true
        }
    }

    if found{
        likeButton.enabled = false
    }
    else{
        likeButton.enabled = true
    }
```

if the post id is already in my liked list the likeButton will be disable. Unfortunately this last part doesn't work (the button stil clickable).
I'm a beginner so I don't see clearly where's the problem with my code
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

```
if id == id
```

While not completely familiar with swift, this comparison will always hold true. Try renaming one of the variables that you are comparing.